# How do I return a class object from a thread and create a vector of returned objects?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, return-value

I want to use C++11 `std::thread`. I am writing a code to parse JSON files and the parsing is not dependent on each other. I have 900 files and to increase the speed of execution I want to create as many threads and make the execution parallel.

My problem is at the moment the function I want to pass to the `std::thread` is a function of a class and it returns the parsed object as a JSON object from which I create a `std::vector`.

I googled 'returning values from threads' and I am getting the tutorials of using `async`,  is there no other way other than async? I went through the async tutorials I am not able to understand how it's launching new threads.

Following is my code:

```
for (auto it = jsonFilesList.begin(); it != jsonFilesList.end(); it++) {
        std::ifstream jsonFile;
        jsonFile.open(*it);
        jf = json::parse(jsonFile);
        jsonFile.close();
        jsonObjects.push_back(jf);
    }
```

I want to pass the function `parse(jsonFile)` to my threads numbering the count of total JSON files, and return the json object, which I will use to create a `std::vector` of jsonObjects.

How can I do this?

Comment: As your searching has said, use `std::async`.  You can see example code, and all of the reference material here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async

Comment: Trying to learn advanced C++ techniques, like multithreaded code, by implementing a simple task is a fairly good approach to learning those techniques. Unfortunately, C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today, and the appropriate techniques for doing this can't really be explained in one or two brief paragraphs on Stackoverflow. To learn how to use execution threads to parallelize processing, there are no alternatives to learning it from a good C++ textbook, which will have several chapters that discuss this.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you for the comment. Is there no other way other than async? I went through the async tutorials I am not able to understand how its launching new threads. But ok, if thats the only way I will look over it. Thanks.

Comment: @TheWhiteCloud There are several ways, but using `std::async` is probably the easiest, as it abstracts away the thread and just gives you a `std::future`. Hard to get something more simple in c++ I'm afraid.

Comment: `std::thread` provides no way to get the return value from the function.  `std::async`, by returning a `std::future`, does.  You're going to have to bite the bullet and learn how to use `async`.  Its really not that hard.  It can be as simple as `auto future = std::async(std::launch::async, my_function, parameters); do_stuff; auto returned_valued = future.get();`

Comment: What is it you don't understand about `async`? `async` just launches a pool of threads once and then redirects your work to the pool, so there is not really the need to know how it launches threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `std::async` seems like a good approach, since it return a `std::future` from which you can get the returned value.

Here is a short example that you could use as an idea to get going.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <vector>

int doWork(int i) {
    return i*2;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> results;
    std::vector<std::future<int>> work;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        work.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &doWork, i));
    }

    // do some other stuff, or nothing
    // before getting the results from all the futures

    for (auto& future : work) {
        results.emplace_back(future.get());
    }

    for(auto i : results) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

[std::future](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) also has member functions like valid, wait, wait_for and wait_until if you want more flexibility in how you retrieve the value.

Comment: Thank you very much...made it easy to understand the implementation.

Comment: @TheWhiteCloud No problem. You can accept the answer by pressing the grey checkmark on the left if you feel like this answered your question.