# How do I pass a function from another class while calling std::async from a function of different class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdasync

I have two classes, `CameraToBEV` and `BEVTest`. The `CameraToBEV` contains the function `process()`.

```
class CameraToBEV : 
{
    public:
        CameraToBEV(std::vector<Point2f>, cv::Point2f, cv::Point2f);
        /*
            process(json Object, ROI Bounding box, Output Dimensions, Input Dimensions)
        */
        cv::Mat process(json&, std::vector<Point2f> = { Point2f(765,57), Point2f(1860,57), Point2f(27, 1000) ,Point2f(1800, 1000) }, Point2f=Point2f(1920,1080), Point2f=Point2f(1920, 1080));
};
```

And the class BEVTest contains the function `runtests()` which calls the function `process()` in a for loop.

```
void BEVTest::runTests()
{   
    CameraToBEV cbevObj(RoiBbox, OutputDim, InputDim);

    std::vector<std::future<cv::Mat>> processingThread;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonObjects.size(); i++) {

            processingThread.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &CameraToBEV::process,this, jsonObjects[i]));
            
                
        }
    
}
```

I am trying to do multithreading using `std::async` of the `for loop` so that the process function gets executed parallelly for each JSON object.

But when I build this code I am getting the following error;

```
Error   C2672   'std::async': no matching overloaded function found 
 
Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'std::future<_Select_invoke_traits<decay<_Ty>::type,decay<_ArgTypes>::type...>::type> std::async(std::launch,_Fty &&,_ArgTypes &&...)'
```

So I tried another way of calling `std::async`

```
processingThread.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &cbevObj.process,this, jsonObjects[i]));
```

and

```
processingThread.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &cbevObj.process,jsonObjects[i]));
```

and

```
processingThread.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &cbevObj.process,jsonObjects[i], ROIBbox, OutputDim, InputDim));
```

Still, I am getting errors.

**Note:**

> I am able to call `std::async` without any error or problem if I call
> the function of the same class from another function of the same class
> which has a `for`  loop, as [mentioned in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65829293/11967838) It's only when I am calling a function of a
> different class from another class that has `for` loop that I am
> facing errors.

**EDIT:** After trying the comments

```
processingThread.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &CameraToBEV::process,&cbevObj, jsonObjects[i], RoiBbox, OutputDim, InputDim));
```

and alternately without passing default values to process()

```
processingThread.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &CameraToBEV::process,&cbevObj, jsonObjects[i]));
```

The error is:

```
Error   C2672   'std::async': no matching overloaded function found 

Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'std::future<_Select_invoke_traits<decay<_Ty>::type,decay<_ArgTypes>::type...>::type> std::async(std::launch,_Fty &&,_ArgTypes &&...)'   

Error   C2672 std::vector<std::future<cv::Mat>,std::allocator<std::future<cv::Mat>>>::emplace_back': no matching overloaded function found
```

Decleration of jsonObjects in BEVTests:

```
class BEVTest
{
    Point2f InputDim, OutputDim;
    std::vector<Point2f> RoiBbox;
    std::string outputPath, inputJsonPath;
    std::vector<json> jsonObjects;

public:  
    BEVTest(std::string, std::string, std::vector<cv::Point2f>, cv::Point2f, cv::Point2f);
    void loadData(); 
    void runTests();
    json parseJson(std::string);
};
```

Comment: Hint: if the member function you want to run using `std::async` is `CameraToBEV::process` then the parameter passed immediately after `&CameraToBEV::process` should be a pointer to a valid `CameraToBEV` instance.

Comment: @G.M. thank you for the hint, so as you say I tried passing &cbevObj which is a pointer to valid CameraToBEV object immediately after the &CameraToBEV::process,  but error persist.

Comment: Please add an edit section to your post showing the new `std::async` call and error.  Please also show the declaration of `jsonObjects`.

Comment: Hi  @G.M. updated with Edit as you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment if the member function you want to run using std::async is `CameraToBEV::process` then the parameter passed immediately after `&CameraToBEV::process` should be a pointer to a valid `CameraToBEV` instance.

In addition, `std::async` will, by default, pass parameters by value.  However the function you're calling has the signature...

```
cv::Mat process(json&, std::vector<Point2f> = { Point2f(765,57), Point2f(1860,57), Point2f(27, 1000) ,Point2f(1800, 1000) }, Point2f=Point2f(1920,1080), Point2f=Point2f(1920, 1080));
```

so it expects the first parameter as a non-const reference to a `json` object.  The call to `std::async` should therefore be (untested)...

```
processingThread.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &CameraToBEV::process, &cbevObj, std::ref(jsonObjects[i])));
```

(Note the use of `std::ref`)

Comment: OK...cool..thankyou very much...the edit u suggested along with passing default parameters did the job....thank you so much...